# PHP sees my function as undefined (oop) gives fatal error

Tags: php, oop

I searched for this, but most of the questions were about mysql/mysqli. I couldn't find out why I get an error which is the next:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function connect() in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\xy\xy.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\xy\xy.php on line 11

The way I got this error message: I have an oop php file with a class in it and within that there's a function (function connect()), this is for database connection.

```
class dbh {

private $servername;
private $username;
private $password;
private $dbname;

protected function connect(/*$conn*/) {
    $this->servername = "localhost";
    $this->username = "root";
    $this->password = "";
    $this->dbname = "carsale";

    $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);
    return $conn;
}
```

I require the separated php on the main page, and I call the connect() function, but instead of connecting it gives the error and this is not about mysqli.

*(I couldn't find any typos.)*

Comment: Show the code where you call `connect` function. Obviously you misunderstand how to call __function__ and how to call __method of class__.

Comment: You need to show the code where the error occurs,,,

Comment: I won't paste the whole code because it's huge. I just call it like this, connect(); and I tried connect($conn); too.

Comment: We **have to** see where you call it... Just show us that line for now

Comment: It's not a function so you can't call it like a function. This is a method so you can only call it on an object, and because it is protected you can't call it from outside the object.

Comment: Now it's just between two php tags, in the body (<?php connect(); ?>), because after this I have a form with action (that's why I need the connection).

Comment: Don't mix PHP and HTML. This will lead to messy code.

Comment: First I didn't mixed it, but didn't worked, I had to try if it works this way.

Comment: Even if you decide to make it public, then you need to create an object first. You already know how to create objects, because you created one in the code `new mysqli`. You can then call methods of that object, but given that you just use the method to create an object of `mysqli` your whole `dbh` becomes useless. Just remove that class and use mysqli without it or create a proper database abstraction library.

Answer (score 0):

Make the connect() method public instead of protected

Comment: I tried, but still the same.